# Eigenvectors of (0,0,0)

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the eigenvectors of

$$\mathbf{A}=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & 2 \\
5 & -3 & 3 \\
-1 & 0 & -2
\end{bmatrix}$$

Eigenvalue are $-1$ (because of repeated roots). I find $(1,-1,0)^T$, and the other eigenvectors are dependent. Is it correct to say that the other two eigenvectors are $(0,0,0)^T$?

Answer (score 1):

Per definition $0$ is never an eigenvector. Otherwise it would be an eigenvector for *every* eigenvalue, since $A0=\lambda 0$ holds for all $A$ and $\lambda$. This doesn't say anything about $A$.

> **Definition:** Let $A$ be an $(n\times n)$ matrix. A scalar $\lambda$ is an *eigenvalue* of $A$ iff there exists a vector $v\neq 0$ such that $Av=\lambda v$. Any such vector $v$ is then called an *eigenvector* of $A$ to the eigenvalue $\lambda$.